# Upgrade Mercurial installation to use a different version of Python

Tags: linux, mercurial, kiln

I have been banging on this for hours now.

I am trying to push my repo changes to kiln but I get this error:

```
certificate checking requires Python 2.6
```

I have already installed a parallel install of Python 2.6 by following the instructions from this [link](http://www.geekymedia.com/tech-articles/rhel5-centos5-rpms-for-python-2-5-and-2-6/), but the error still persists. The system is ClearOS 5.2 by the way.

My first question is, will installing/upgrading mercurial break my existing install?

I tried to re-install following these intstructions [link1](https://serverfault.com/questions/234718/cannot-install-mercurial-properly-pythonpath-error) and [i lost the other link], but encountered another error.
Then I found this command debuginstall and here's the result:

```
[root@system mercurial-1.7.5]# hg debuginstall
Checking encoding (UTF-8)...
Checking installed modules (/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/mercurial)...
Checking templates...
Checking patch...
Checking commit editor...
Checking username...
 no username supplied (see "hg help config")
 (specify a username in your configuration file)
1 problems detected, please check your install!
```

My another question is, can I just change the existing hg's settings to just use the python26 which is already installed?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Install your own python (of whatever version you need) to a separate directory (e.g.: `/usr/local/python-2.7.2/`) and then change the invocation of hg from `#!/usr/bin/python` to `#!/usr/local/python-2.7.2/bin/python`  This way you don't disturb the existing/system installation, but you can use the version you want only where you need it.  The only annoying part about this is dealing with two sets of libraries, since this is really maintaining two parallel installations.  So if the 'extra' python needs libraries, you must install them manually using the invocation and paths of the extra installation.  Sounds complicated, but if you only need it for one program, then you set it up once and it's good to go.

Comment: thanks! I tried it but did not work. I edited the hg file in /usr/bin and got this msg: "-bash: /usr/bin/hg: /usr/bin/python2.6/bin/python: bad interpreter: Not a directory" I removed the /bin/python part but still did not work. I think it's the libdir variable which is still pointing to the other python.

Comment: This is the same problem/error msgs I encountered yesterday, that's why I ended up trying to install/re-install/upgrade HG to use the newer python.